# can't connect to mongolab with node.js on heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I am having trouble making node.js and mongodb with mongolab work on heroku. I have read other issues like [How do I setup MongoDB database on Heroku with MongoLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660519/how-do-i-setup-mongodb-database-on-heroku-with-mongolab) and [How do I manage MongoDB connections in a Node.js web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656574/how-to-manage-mongodb-connections-in-a-nodejs-webapp) but I still can not set up my connection. In the logs it says [Error: failed to connect to ...]

I have takend the db, host and port from the MONGOLAB_URI process env.I have the following code:

```
var mongoUri = mongodb://heroku_app17328644:{password}@ds037518.mongolab.com //taken from process.env.MONGOLAB_URI 

var host = 'mongodb://heroku_appXXXXXX:{password}@ds037518.mongolab.com';
var port = '37518';
var database = 'heroku_appXXXXXX';

Provider.db = new Db(database, new Server(host, port, { safe: true }, { auto_reconnect: true }, {}));
Provider.db.open(function(err, db){
console.log(db); //null
if (err) console.log(err);
else console.log('success');
});
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What's the error message that you get?

Comment: He gets `Error: failed to connect to ...` and the `db` is null :)

Comment: That's not the full error message...

Comment: [Error: failed to connect to mongodb://heroku_appXXXXXX:{password}@ds037518.mongolab.com] this is the error I am getting

Answer (score 14):

The core issue seems to be that you're trying to use a MongoDB URI as a hostname.

Here's how to connect using a URI and [`MongoClient`](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/36666163412/introducing-mongoclient):

```js
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var uri = 'mongodb://user:pass@host:port/db';
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, function (err, db) {
    /* adventure! */
});
```

Of course you'll want to substitute the `user`, `pass`, `host`, `port`, and `db` in the `uri` for your actual connect parameters. If you're using the [MongoLab add-on for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab) you can get the URI from the environment like this:

```js
var uri = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
```

When using `MongoClient` safe mode is the default, so that option can be left out. To specify `auto_reconnect` simply pass it as a server option.

```js
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var uri = 'mongodb://user:pass@host:port/db';
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, { server: { auto_reconnect: true } }, function (err, db) {
    /* adventure! */
});
```

Comment: Hi, I kind of have the same issue. When I do 'heroku config' it doesn't return the MONGODB_URI, it only returns the heroku link. I tried with this too 'heroku config:get MONGODB_URI' but it doesn't return anything. My code link is : https://github.com/Aritra1704/TutorialRestAPI/blob/master/server/db/mongoose.js 

heroku push is working but the logs show failed to connect to port 27017. What might I be doing wrong? node version 8.9.4

Answer (score 4):

Here's is how I do it. This way, my application connects to the "test" database on my development machine and the "mongolab" database when deployed and running on Heroku.

```
mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost/test';
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || mongoURI);
```

Answer (score 4):

In my own case, I queried the configuration settings `heroku config` and it turns out that the mongodb is added as `MONGODB_URI`.

So, I added process.env.MONGODB_URI to the uri such as:

```
var uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI || process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI;
```