# node.js - app on Heroku keeps crashing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I am used to localHost dev, and am new to production development, and am working to get an app running on Heroku

After following the steps in the 'getting started' guide on Heroku..

```
heroku ps
=== web (1X): `node app.js`
web.1: crashed 2014/02/27 12:27:37 (~ 11m ago)
```

Might it be my MongoLab connection code?

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var uri = 'mongodb://user:pass@host:port/db'
//substituted the user, pass, host, port, and db for my actual parameters

mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri, { server: { auto_reconnect: true } }, function (err, db) {
    var db = this.db('myFirstDemo');
});
```

I replaced my localHost connection code shown below, with the code above, based on [can't connect to mongolab with node.js on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076335/cant-connect-to-mongolab-with-node-js-on-heroku)

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017,
                                                { 'native_parser' : true }));
var db = mongoclient.db('myFirstDemo');


mongoclient.open(function (err, mongoclient) {
    if (err) throw err
    app.listen(9999);
    console.log("Express server started on port 9999");
});
```

Comment: Run the command `heroku logs` to see what is happening specifically.

Comment: As @KrisHollenbeck mentioned, you should use the command heroku logs to see what's going on under the hood. You can also find my example here on connecting: https://github.com/chrischang12/mejan-boilerplate/blob/master/app.js. Feel free to write to us at support@mongolab.com if you need more help!

Comment: @ChrisChang how does the MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://localhost/mejan_playground' ? And can you choose any port for the app.listen()..? Thanks for commenting

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck basically, it's a mongodb connection issue.. I can't seem to add any MongoDB addon before uploading my codeset, yet I need to get the MONGODB_URI from the addon to include it in my app.js!? It feels like a strange loop..

Comment: @StackThis if you're using an addon, you can set the mongodb_uri to process.env.MONGOLAB_URI to access the URI from your addon. for the port you can use process.env.PORT as defined by heroku

Comment: @ChrisChang thanks for that.. This in the log though: `TypeError: Cannot call method 'collection' of undefined`.. Any suggestions?

Comment: @StackThis can you email me at support@mongolab.com? Mention my name and we'll discuss it there, our support line is monitored more closely than SO